# android add fragment advice

Tags: android, android-fragments

In my application I have two fragments A and B. A fragment contains Google map and listview inside on it B fragment Google map only.

I want open B fragment from A fragment but when I press back button it has to go to A fragment without loading data.

```
public void addPage(final DefaultFragment pDefaultFragment, final boolean isAddToBackStack){
            FragmentTransaction transaction = mFragmentManager.beginTransaction();
            transaction.add(R.id.content_frame, pDefaultFragment);
            //transaction.replace(R.id.content_frame, pDefaultFragment);
            if (isAddToBackStack) transaction.addToBackStack(null);
            transaction.commitAllowingStateLoss();            
    }
```

I use this code for adding fragment

```
Bframent b = new Bfragment();
addPage(b,true);
```

I know differences between `transaction. add` and `transaction.replace`. My problem is when I use transaction.add A fragment's map doesn't destroy it stays above of B fragment's map when pressing button. But when use transaction.replace after press back button data loads again.

So could anyone tell me what should I do to Press back button without to load data without any problem on view also.

Answer (score -1):

On back press just provide your fragment null;